# Return first letters of words in a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, indexof, charat

I keep getting an infinite loop and don't understand why my code doesn't work and keeps crashing the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function firstLetter(word, letter) {
            var firstLetter = "";
            while(word.indexOf(" ", letter) !== -1) {
                letter = word.indexOf(" ") + 1;
                console.log(word.charAt(letter));

            }
            return firstLetter; 
        } 
        console.log(firstLetter('Hi!, my name is Jessica.'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not much of the code makes any sense. Apart from calling the function with only one argument when it accepts two, you never change `firstLetter`, try to get the index of an index, and the function seems to be set to return only one character anyway.

Comment: Also not a good idea to use a variable with the same name as the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way out of your `while` loop. It keeps finding the first space in the string, continuously, forever, because `letter = word.indexOf(" ")` will only ever find the first space. You should remember the value you got from the call to `indexOf` in the loop (`while ((letter = word.indexOf(" ", letter)) !== -1)`) rather than using a second call, so it picks up where you left off and you work your way through the string. You should also default `letter` when it's not supplied (`letter = letter || 0;` at the beginning will do for this function; that sets `letter` to `0` if it has any *falsy** value).

Alternately, you'd use `split` and then take the first letter of each entry.

Note that I'm not providing explicit code as I figure this is a learning exercise.

---

Separately, you probably want to add to `firstLetter` in the loop.

---

* "falsy" - JavaScript has "falsy" values (values that coerce to `false` when used as booleans) and "truthy" values (ones that coerce to `true` when used as booleans). The falsy values are `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, and of course, `false`. All others are truthy. When you don't supply an argument for a parameter when calling a function, the parameter gets the value `undefined`.